# Use json app settings instead of system environment variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, environment-variables, appsettings

I am working with a asp.net core project which will have 2 environments that I deploy to a single server, staging and production. My aim is to make staging use the appsetting.json file instead of window environment variable.

I have set up a environment variable on the server.
[Environment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH2ke.png)

In my appsettings.json file, I have the process setting with a different value.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Process": "Not ABC"
}
```

This is the code to retrieve it in my project.

```
string process = _config.GetValue<string>("Process");
```

Issue is both staging and production are on the same server meaning they using the same environment system variable. Both situations, the enviroment variable overrides the one in appsettings.json.

I want staging to use the appsettings.json. Is there a way to do this?

I tried looking over the internet and can't find any solution.

Comment: Who are you hosting with if I may ask?

Comment: Pulsant server.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with them

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging the information from documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

I propose the following:

1. Create app settings for both production and Staging.
2. Create two releases, one for staging and one for production.
3. In the production configuration file, omit the values you want to load from environment variables.
4. Add the environment provider first and the app setting one second
5. In the Staging app config, add your values.

This way, the Staging value will come from the app settings file and the production from the environment variable.

Comment: Thanks. In step 3, do you mean remove it from production app settings? In step 4, when you say environment provider, you mean environment variable? Not sure what you mean by adding it first and how would that make a difference.